# Basic MVC nullable char validation

Tags: validation, asp.net-mvc-4, attributes

I have the following in one of my view models:

```
public char? MyChar { get; set }
```

I noticed there appears to be no client-side validation on the textbox for `MyChar`, and it's possible for a user to submit a string that is too long for this `char` to my controller (it simply doesn't bind and remains null).

So, I added the `[MaxLength]` annotation. Client-side validation now works as expected, but when I submit a valid value to the server, I get the following exception in my event logs:

```
Exception information: 
    Exception type: InvalidCastException 
    Exception message: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Char' to type 'System.Array'.
   at System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.MaxLengthAttribute.IsValid(Object value)
```

How can I validate the max length of a `char` correctly both client-side and server-side?

**What I've Tried**

For now, I've created my own `MaxLength` attribute for it to work with `char` types, but it feels like a heavy approach.

Comment: Since your editing data and using a view model so you could always make the view model property a `string` with `[MaxLength]` and then convert to char when mapping to the data model.

Comment: @StephenMuecke - thanks a lot for your reply. I did consider this approach to be honest, I just wanted to avoid having to cater for this type change the other way too (i.e. from entity to view model, I shouldn't have to cast to string in an ideal world).

Comment: I'll check the source code later, but I suspect it's either that or you would need to create your own `ValidationAttribute` that implements `IClientValidatable`

Comment: As I suspected, the attribute requires that the value be either a string or an array. Refer [source code](https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/MaxLengthAttribute.cs) -

Comment: @StephenMuecke - I thought so. I've gone with the `string` approach for now and map it back to my data entity like so: `MyChar = this.MyCharString?[0]`. Sorted. Not ideal but I suppose, to the view at least, it *is* kind of a string.